# use grep/sed/awk to extract string corresponding to certain field

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

On my Fedora system, I get the following:

```
$  cat /proc/net/arp 
IP address      HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
130.48.0.1       0x1         0x2         80:4b:c7:10:3e:41     *        wlp1s0
```

How can I pipe the result of the Device (in this case the answer is wlp1s0) using a screen editor such as sed or grep or awk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get interface name used to get out of a computer, you can use this:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $5}'
eth0
```

It will always get the correct, even if more than one inf is online.

Comment: Thank you. This is even more useful than the answer to my question, for which also I am grateful!!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR>1{print $6}' < /proc/net/arp
```

If we're after the first line (to get rid of the header "Device"), print sixth field (separated by whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/{print $6}' /proc/net/arp 
wlp1s0
```

- `/^[0-9]/` selects lines that start with digit, ip
- `print $6` prints the 6th colum being the Device

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your fields are tab-separated, if the Device always appears as the last column:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{print $NF}' file
wlp1s0
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; next} {print $(f["Device"])}' file
wlp1s0
```

Comment: This does not give the correct answer. It rather gives the line: awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; next} {print $(f["Device"])}'  /proc/net/arp
130.48.0.1       0x1         0x2         80:4b:c7:10:3e:41     *        wlp1s0

Comment: Then your file is simply not tab-separated.

Answer (score 0):

Four methods:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; next} {print $(f["HW"])}' </proc/net/arp

awk 'NR==2{print $NF}' < /proc/net/arp

sed -nr '/^[0-9]/s#(.*)* (.*)#\2#gp' /proc/net/arp

sed -nr '/^[0-9]/s#(.*)\*[^a-z]*(.*)#\2#gp'  /proc/net/arp
```